# How to see if a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(C)$-measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm given the following universe: $\Omega =\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and a collection $C = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\},\{3, 4, 5, 6\}\}$. I was first asked to determine the $\sigma$-algebra for this collection, which I found to be:

$$\sigma(C) = \{\emptyset, \{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 5\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{1, 2, 5, 6\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6\}, \Omega\}$$

I was now given a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ where:

$$X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
    2,& \text{if } \omega \in [1, 4]\\
    7, &\text{if } \omega \in [5, 6]\\
\end{cases}$$

I'm asked to see if this function is $\sigma(C)$-measurable, but I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-algebra seems to be correct. To check if this random variable is measureable you have to check if the preimage $X^{-1}(A)$ of every set $A\in\cal B(\Bbb R)$ is contained in $\sigma(C)$. As your random variable only takes 2 values this is pretty easy to check. Depending whether the values $2$, $7$ are contained in $A$ your preimage is $\emptyset$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{5,6\}$ or $\Omega$.

Comment: So in this case, it is a $\sigma$(C)-measurable function since all the sets included in the preimage are included in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, since all possible preimages are element of $\sigma(C)$ it is measurable.